# dep interpreter not found

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-zeppelin

I try to use the dep interpreter in Zeppelin.

I use the %dep declaration within my zeppelin notebook.

However, I end up with the error "dep interpreter not found"

The %dep interpreter is configured within the interpreter section correctly
[image]

Comment: Can you please check if `org.apache.zeppelin.spark.DepInterpreter` is inside your `conf/zeppelin-site.xml` as well as post logs from `logs/zeppelin-<username>-<hostname>.log`?

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, I found [this HCC thread](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/38130/how-to-import-play-json-library-using-zeppeline.html) with an insight into recent versions:

> %dep is deprecated.
>
> Go to Spark interpreter settings and click edit button to add the
>   dependency.